# unmet dependencies when installing zoom: Depends: libxcb-xtest0 but it is not installable E

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I m trying to install zoom on ubuntu, doing thru graphic installer did not work, i tried thru terminal with 'sudo apt-get install ./zoom-package'

and it gave me this error:

```
the following packages have unmet dependencies:
 zoom : Depends: libxcb-xtest0 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

i did

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

still did not work. any ideas?

Comment: Package `libxcb-xtest0` is available for supported Ubuntu's https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libxcb-xtest0&searchon=names ... Ubuntu 18.04 test : `$ sudo gdebi Downloads/zoom_amd64.deb` → No issues, libxcb-xtest0, etc. installed OK.

Comment: all i did was updating things and std installation worked for me

Comment: @karel, thx u all and Karel

Comment: In the “Software & Updates” window, go to the first tab, “Ubuntu Software” and enable the checkboxes for mutliverse and universe. Then run `sudo apt --fix-broken install` in a terminal window. Now, the Zoom install should succeed.